# How to implement UI in mobile application

Tags: user-interface, mobile

I have a hybrid mobile app.
The framework is vanilla Javascript (i.e. no React, Angular, Vue, etc..).
The GUI work as expected (i.e. the buttons trigger the correct functionality) but the UI is lucking.
I have a UX  / UI design in place, in form of an idea and example sketches, but not in any framework (e.g. no Figma files).
I use Bootstrap inconsistently in the app, for some of the buttons and found about [Material Design Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/).

I see many blogs about UI design and design tools, such as Figma, Sketch, Adobe XD, etc.
In my case, I already have the UX/UI design results. (although just conceptually - not in any files).
So I'm looking for UI implementation (not design) tools / packages / approaches.

What is the best way to implement the UI?
Could I just start implementing bits and pieces of the UI?
Or should I use a specific framework/platform/mockup ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i would advice you implement the ui in bits as you would have better understanding about the code running your ui and how to easily connect the gui to functionality. tools like figma have features that can convert designs to html/css code buut that would require having to work on design files.